# Google Sheets: Is it possible to target a cell with a Note in it?

Tags: google-sheets

IS it possible to do an "IF" funtion to do something to a cell based on whether or not a cell has a "Note" in it?

Comment: Can you provide more details in your question such as your inputs and your expected output? there is no existing function to check if a cell has a note but it might done using apps script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use apps script.
To get a string (e.g: myString) in a cell (e.g: myCell) use

```
    myString= myCell.getNote();
    < ... test myString to do something ... >
```

To put a string in a cell use:

```
    myCell.setNote(myString);
```